# change css of button when mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
#buttonShareMap:disabled {
    background:black;
}
```

will change the colour of my button to black if it is disabled.

However if disabled, and the user holds the cursor over the button it changes to blue, which is the colour it is normally if the button is enabled
class="edit blue btn".....

I would like to keep the button black at all times when it is disabled...So is it something like:

```
.buttonShareMap:disabled:hover
{
    background:black;
}
```

cant get it working...any ideas? ta

Also, the cursor changes to a mouse over hand...when held over the disabled button. I would like it to remain as a cursor and only change to mouse over hand if the button is enabled?

Comment: Once the element is disabled I believe that it no longer raises *any* events, hence `hover` will not fire on it.

Comment: Havey you tried with ":active"?

Comment: use !important to override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `!important` and that should work. The background probably is probably being over written by the cascade.  It would be better to find out where and correct it instead of `!important` but if you need a quick and dirty solution it will work.  Also, you can set  the cursor to be the default one when it is disabled.  All together the CSS would be:

```
#buttonShareMap:disabled {
  background:black !important;
  cursor:default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A disabled button wont be able to catch the JS events like hover, mouseover etc. If you want to change your disabled button color, you can directly do it using CSS. You can do something like:

<style>
input.button:disabled{ background: #000; color: #FFF; cursor: default;}
</style>

<input type="button" class="button" value="Button" disabled>

If the background color is not picked you can add an !important with the CSS rule.
```